# Flutter: show a loading widget only if it's still loading after n seconds

Tags: flutter

I have a simple `Loading` widget that I display when I'm getting data from Firestore. I use Stateful widgets with a variable called `_isLoading` which is usually set to `false` but changes to `true` while I'm getting data, and if `_isLoading == true` I show the `Loading` widget.

```
setState(() {
   isLoading = true;
});

await someFunctionToUpdateData();

setState(() {
   isLoading = false;
});
.
.
.
// somewhere in the Build method
_isLoading ? Loading() : MainWidgetWithData()
```

This works perfectly fine but I'm finding that often the data comes back very quickly, so I get this effect where the loading widget flashes on the screen very briefly before the data is displayed (which I don't want). So I want to be able to wait a few seconds before showing the Loading widget, like this:

```
someFunctionToUpdateData();

// if someFunctionToUpdateData() is not done after n seconds, then:
setState(() {
   isLoading = true;
});

// once someFunctionToUpdateData() has finished:
setState(() {
   isLoading = false;
});
```

Comment: **Please try these two method:-** **Future Delayed**: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/dart/future+delayed+flutter ***OR*** **Timer**: https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-flutter-timer-class-timer-periodic/ **Note**: More Methods are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being `someFunctionToUpdateData()` an async function I recommend using `.timeout()`:

```
final response = await someFunctionToUpdateData().timeout(const Duration(seconds: 4));
```

If **after 4 seconds** the function did not return anything (or complete), it will throw a [TimeoutException](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.0/dart-async/TimeoutException-class.html), or you can specify what to do as:

```
final response = await someFunctionToUpdateData().timeout(const Duration(seconds: 4),
onTimeout: myFunction());
```

Read more here > [Documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.0/dart-async/Future/timeout.html)

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. Just for those who want to do this in the future this is exactly what I did: `Future futureFunc = someFunctiontoUpdateData()` then `futureFunc.timeOut(...)` then `futureFunc.whenComplete(...)`